# <content:link> is showing error text if there is no URL

Tags: jsf, error-handling

I got on my website a Image that has to be clickable. Everything works fine, but only in cases on the current website a URL is provided for the Image. If there is URL, there appears a error message that ruins the content of the website.

How can I make the error message not display.

Here is code. Thank you!

```
<content:link link="#{cc.attrs.teaser.teaserLinkModel}" value="">
        <content:graphicImage graphic="#{cc.attrs.teaser.graphic}"
            renderDimensions="false" />
    </content:link>
```

Comment: What is the "content" namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got a solution.. The thing is, I'm working on someone elses code and didn't know what of options (functions) there already exist. After analysing the code, a saw there is the "rendered" attribute that behaves just like a "if" condition checker.
Anyways, here is my solution to this problem, maybe it helps someone.

```
<!-- Image is link -->
    <h:outputLink rendered="#{cc.attrs.teaser.hasTeaserLink}">
        <content:link link="#{cc.attrs.teaser.teaserLinkModel}" value="">
            <content:graphicImage graphic="#{cc.attrs.teaser.graphic}" renderDimensions="false" />
        </content:link>
    </h:outputLink>
    <!-- Image is no link -->
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{not cc.attrs.teaser.hasTeaserLink}" value="#" >
        <content:graphicImage graphic="#{cc.attrs.teaser.graphic}" renderDimensions="false" />
    </ui:fragment>
```

For "Image is no link" I didn't use the "h:outputLink" tag, because it puts a ">" char in front the image and ruins the page content. 
This maybe not the best solution, but it did work for me.